# How to create a second index.php?

Tags: themes, child-theme

I need a duplicate of `index.php`, but slightly modified. I added a "vote it up" plugin. So, I want the user to select how to display posts - by new or by popular. I know what to add to second `index.php`, but how to create a second `index.php`, thats the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elaborating on Rachel Baker's answer:

Copy the index.php file and name it something like popular.php. At the very top, paste the following:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Posts by Popular
*/
?>
```

Now, go in to the WordPress admin and create a new page, called something like "By Popular". On the right-hand side, select the "Posts by Popular" template where it says "Template" ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsxUI.png)). Publish the page, and when you view it you should see your new page.

Create a link to this page in the nav menu or wherever, and then your users will be able to access the new page.

Comment: This was really easy to do, but actually when I apply the template vote it up plugin is not working correctly even before adding changes. So, I will have to get rid of this idea..

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new page, using a modified template file - and send users to that page if they choose to display posts "by popular"

Comment: modified template file? A little advice where to start with this?

Answer (score 0):

When i do this kinds of modification i always use [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) Because its the easy way to doing it. And if i mess the child theme up i can just copy files form the main theme anytime.

If you never tried the child theme. This might be the right time for you. ;) Just make a child theme copy the index.php file form original theme and place it to the child theme directory and edit.

Comment: Can you help me with understanding of this? So, I create a new folder in my themes folder, put style.css and my modified index.php. The question is how to make wordpress understand when to switch index.php?

Comment: @Sisir I believe OP is asking for a way how to **let users switch** the two different views. Therefore child theme offers a little help for this usecase. Aside from that, yes, using a child themes really is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If the OP is asking about creating a secondary index.php using a different theme, then it's not so simple: WP loads theme-specific constants right at load time and won't have it any other way. The only way to temporarily force a different theme is to create a plugin that will override the 'stylesheet' and optionally 'template' options, like this:

```
if ($GLOBALS['USE_SECONDARY_THEME']) {
    add_filter('stylesheet',function() { return 'mytheme-secondary'; });
    add_filter('template',function() { return 'mytheme'; }); // if the secondary theme is a child of mytheme
}
```

And then, in index-secondary.php, do

```
$USE_SECONDARY_THEME=true;
```

right before the usual

```
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/blog/wp-load.php' );
```

that should be in a WordPress index file.